# Pandas: Difference of float numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've ran into a weird issue here. I have a dataframe `df` like below:

```
In [1561]: df
Out[1561]: 
      A     B
0  16.3  1.10
1  23.2  1.33
2  10.7 -0.43
3   5.7 -2.01
4   5.4 -1.86
5  23.5  3.14
```

I'm comparing every two adjacent rows of column `A` and storing the difference in a new column:

```
In [1562]: df['new_diff'] = (df.A - df.A.shift(-1)).fillna(0)
In [1563]: df
Out[1563]: 
      A     B  new_diff
0  16.3  1.10      -6.9
1  23.2  1.33      12.5
2  10.7 -0.43       5.0
3   5.7 -2.01       0.3
4   5.4 -1.86     -18.1
5  23.5  3.14       0.0
```

When I do a check to find out rows where `new_diff` is `5.0`, I get an empty dataframe. But, it works fine when I do a check on `< 5.0` or `> 5.0`. See below:

```
In [1567]: df[df['new_diff'] == 5.0]
Out[1567]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, new_diff]
Index: []

In [1568]: df[df['new_diff'] > 5.0]
Out[1568]: 
      A     B  new_diff 
1  23.2  1.33      12.5  

In [1569]: df[df['new_diff'] < 5.0]
Out[1569]: 
      A     B  new_diff
0  16.3  1.10      -6.9
2  10.7 -0.43       5.0
3   5.7 -2.01       0.3
4   5.4 -1.86     -18.1
5  23.5  3.14       0.0
```

Please let me know what am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is with float precision, need [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
print (df['new_diff'].tolist())
[-6.899999999999999, 12.5, 4.999999999999999, 0.2999999999999998, -18.1, 0.0]

print (df[np.isclose(df['new_diff'], 5)])
      A     B  new_diff
2  10.7 -0.43       5.0
```

Comment: What should be the float precision to make it work like this `df[df['new_diff'] == 5.0]` ?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - ya, float working this way. In my opinion main problem is pandas it `round`ing display values, so is problematic see `5` is not `5`, but `4.999999999999999`

Comment: Ok. Pandas rounding it off is creating this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Or, make the string type the `'new_diff'` in the filter process (doesn't modify the actual data), then check if it equals to `'5.0'`:

```
print(df[df['new_diff'].astype(str)=='5.0'])
```

Output:

```
      A     B  new_diff
2  10.7 -0.43       5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `round` i.e

```
df[df['new_diff'].round() == 5.0]

      A     B  new_diff
2  10.7 -0.43       5.0
```